# Prevent user from closing notifications in R Shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing an R app using "shiny" that uses `cli_progress_bar()` to display the progress of long-running tasks to the user.  I require the progress bar to remain visible at all times.  Is there any way to either:

- Remove the "×" button, so there is no way for the user to close it?

or failing that

- Restore a progress bar that has previously been closed?

MRE:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  cli::cli_progress_bar(name = 'Progress', total = 101)
  for (i in 1:100) {
    cli::cli_progress_update(set = i)
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = shiny::fluidPage(),
                server = server)
```

Comment: You should provide a minimal example of a shiny app using this progress bar

Comment: For other people to copy paste you minimal example to try to do stuff on it to solve your problem

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!  Now added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one progress bar in your app, you can use this CSS solution to remove the "x" button.
There must be a way to give your progress bar an ID so you can specify you want to remove the "x" juste for this one, but i didn't dig further.

```
library(shiny)
library(cli)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
     .shiny-notification-close {
        display: none;
      }
"))
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  cli::cli_progress_bar(name = 'Progress',total = 101)
  for (i in 1:100) {
    cli::cli_progress_update(set = i)
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wonderfully inventive approach – thank you!